# "lessify" a CSS color theme

Tags: css, themes, less, partials

I've inherited a project with a ton of CSS and been assigned the task of modifying it so the color palette can easily be changed.

I've immediately thought of using a CSS preprocessor, tried less and easily switched the colors for variables, so I just have to define a base color and can switch the color theme.

The problem is, every time I switch the color theme I have to either overwrite `colors.less` with the new color settings or modify the `colors.less` import in a ton of files.

What I want is to end up with a single file with a lot of imports (basically one per component or set of components), and on that file when I import colors-red.less instead of colors-blue.less all the components imported right after use the red palette so the theme compiled is red instead of blue, for example.

The problem I am having is that the component files do not get the "globals" with the color definitions so I can't compile the base file that imports those files.

I've read there is the possibility of using "partials" (files starting with _ that won't get compiled independently but imported and then compiled), but my compiler seems to be ignoring this feature, and the eclipse plugin I use for editing and verifying less files also complains about the color variables not being defined on those partials.

How can I can get the partials to work? Is there a better approach to do this task?

Comment: When using Less you create mostly one one project file. That project file imports your other files (partials called by you). You only compile your project file into CSS. Which files are compiled depends of your build process. Take bootstrap as an example, only the `bootstrap.less` file will be compiled.

Comment: Yes, only all imports are compiled separately and then put togheter on one output CSS instead of put together then compiled. That's why my project is not compiling: I need the variables declared on a imported file to be visible to all the following imports.

Comment: Less uses lazy loading and last declaration wins, so you can define your variables afterwards, see: http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-lazy-loading

Comment: Stil, they won't be defined on the imported files, just on the main file, so compilation will break on the imported files. You see what I mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Stil, they won't be defined on the imported files, just on the main file, so >compilation will break on the imported files. You see what I mean?

Nope? example:

mixins.less:

```
.mixin()
{
   color: @color;
}
```

variables.less:

```
@color: orange;
```

project.less:

```
@import "mixins";
@import "variables";
p {
.mixin();
}
```

Now running `lessc project.less` outputs:

```
p {
color:orange;
}
```

Now i change to content of `project.less` as follows:

```
@import "mixins";
@import "variables";
p {
.mixin();
}
@color: red;
```

Then running `lessc project.less` outputs:

```
p {
color:red;
}
```

Comment: Superb! it turns out it was a problem on the eclipse plugin settings for the compiler. somehow the plugin was compiling everything not just the main file, so it halted on error before compiling the main file and that's why I was getting no compiled output at all (I still have to figure out how to avoid the editor giving me an undefined error on every partial file on every line I use those variables, but I can live with that). Thanks a lot for your patience ;-)